# Xamarin Studio (Android) Error Inflating Class <unknown> Unless Cleaned

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio, inflate-exception

### **The Problem:**

After modifying **any** layout file in my Android project in Xamarin Studio, my mainlauncher (SplashActivity) throws the following exception.  The exception continues to throw until I clean my project.

---

### **The Exception:**

> Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class

[image: Exception being thrown]

---

### **Environment:**

I am using the following tools:

```
Xamarin Studio: Version 5.2.1 (build 1)
Xamarin.Android: Version 4.1.0
```

With the following relevant settings:

> Minimum Android Version: Android 4.3 (API level 16)

Computer:

> Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 (x64)

Testing Device:

> Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.3

---

### **Relevant Code:**

*SplashLayout.axml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SPLASH_messageText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*SplashActivity (Trimmed to just the OnCreate)*:

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate (bundle);
    SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SplashLayout);   // <-- this is where the exception is thrown
    MessageTextView = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.SPLASH_messageText);      // Get a reference to our message text view to update the user

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (o => {
        InitialChecking();               // Check to make sure Google Play services are installed
    });
} // end OnCreate
```

---

### **My Research:**

The following is a list of questions that appear related, but are not relevant to my current situation.

- [Xamarin - Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305420/3033053)  - *The error was caused by using a [color state-list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) as a background.  I don't even define a background.*
- [Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021284/3033053)  - *This error was due to using the `android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall` attribute while [targeting an API level that did not support it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) (>14).  My minimum Android Version is API level 16.*
- [InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680508/3033053)  - *The problem was caused by a resource decoding a large bitmap that caused the VM to run out of memory.  I am not loading any images, or drawables.*
- [Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162403/binary-xml-file-line-9-error-inflating-class-fragment) - *I am not using fragments*
- [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21625644/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-6-error-inflating-class-u)  - *OP was using depreciated `AbsoluteLayout`, I am using a `LinearLayout`
- [EditText tag causes Error inflating class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13604028/3033053)  - *Error was caused by `android:scrollY="10dp"`, which is not in my layout.*

---

### **Additional Information:**

- When I clean the solution before debugging, the error is resolved until I modify ***any*** layout file.
- Once this exception is thrown, it will continue to throw until I clean the solution.
- The XML for the activity only has a text view, and it does not call to any drawable resources.  Additionally, `SplashLayout.axml` only contains 12 lines of code.

---

### **The Question:**

- What could be causing this error, and could it happen in production?

Comment: Should there be a question mark in your textAppearance attribute?

Comment: @SpiritMachine there is nothing wrong with the layout, nor the questionmark in the textAppearance attribute. There could be some strangeness with the build process somehow. OP, what version of the tools are you using?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I am using `Xamarin Studio 5.2.1 build 1`.  I've edited the question to reflect that.  Also, I've omitted my InitialChecking() method because I don't believe it's relevant due to where the exception is being thrown.  If there's any other potentially helpful information, please tell me and I will edit my question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try adding this line to your axml files:
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

It might sound unrelated but I had inflation problem once and it is resolved by doing so.